# Get input file value to div

Tags: jquery, file-upload, input

**Hello** i have code below, and I need that i will get file value to `<span>` "filevalue" but i have no idea how to do that with jquery, so please give me some examples

```
<div id="file">
    <input type="file" id="ufile"/> 
    <div id="info">
        <span class="filevalue">file value goes here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#ufile").on("change​​​​​​​​", function() {
    $("#info .filevalue").text(this.value);
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/A6KEJ/